# Python Click library: Set default optiont() value to environment variable

Tags: python-3.x

Using the Python click library
https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

I want to set the default value of an option to be the value of an environment variable.

e.g. the following sets the value of the `--path` option to `$HOME`

```
@click.option('--path', envvar='HOME', help="Path to directory to save")
```

However, I want the user to be able to specify a different path, by manually entering the `--path` option, with the default being `$HOME` if no option was entered.

Something like this

```
@click.option('--path', type=str, default='$HOME', help="Path to directory to save")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare a variable before with the environment value you want, e.g. to get `$HOME`

```
import click
from pathlib import Path

HOME = str(Path.home())

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.option('--path', type=str, default=HOME, help="Path to directory to save")
```

Answer (score 2):

that is not the best way of doing it with click.
You can use `envvar` option, like:

```
@click.option('--gh-token', envvar="GH_TOKEN", help='GitHub API token')
```